# Error loading DLL (think that VC++ runtime is missing)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll, runtime

I ve created some DLL in Visual Studio. Then i wanted to use it in C# application.
On my first machine it worked well, but crashes on laptop with such error "Can't load DLL 'MyDLL.dll'".

I ve used DependencyWalker tool and found a lot of garbage that is missed, some of these:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-DDRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
... and a lot of others ...
```

Tried to install all VC++ runtimes (2013, 2015, 2019). But it does not help.

Thanks.

Comment: The DLLs you've listed are part of Windows itself.

Comment: Dependency walker has false positives. This project / tool is meant to fix that: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: Are you using a debug or a release build?

Comment: Thanks man, drescherjm. You are awesome!! This app showed me that OpenAL dll was missing. Fixed it. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments. Dependency walker has some false positives. There is a new / updated tool that fixes this issue:

https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies